# prevent specific task from running in parallel

Tags: gradle

I have a specific task that when run in `--parallel` can cause the build to break.  Is there anyway to prevent parallel execution on a specific task?  I am thinking of something like the `synchronized` keyword on the method in Java.

Answer (score 2):

No such feature currently exists. You could try to work around with `synchronized` though.